# Cannot stream HD Youtube shows on chrome in linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, video, youtube

All the videos have HD, FHD, UHD options if thay are available.  However, the show I bought, humans, doesn't have 720p option.
**PS:** I bought the HD version and I can watch 720p on my iPhone though client.

**OS:** Arch Linux (Fully upgraded 2019-01-05).
**Chrome Version:** google-chrome 71.0.3578.98-1 (From AUR)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to update your flash plugin or maybe enable HTML5.

In Chrome you can use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flash-html5-for-youtube/omimccinlhlkpjaeaocglgmkbelejlhj) extension, called Flash-HTML5 for YouTube, which enables you to watch HTML5 videos on YouTube using Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  AFAIK, Chrome in linux has integrated flash plugin.  I tried your extension to use html5 player, it doesn't work for me.